# Magento 2 : Disable CDN

Tags: magento2, product-images, cdn

Is their any way we can disable cdn for media url in magento2 ?

I am having issues in order confirmation email.
In products it has cdn link for products images, not what i have added in media url in backend.

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you check the config on the store view scope for :

Admin > Stores > Configuration > Base URLs > Base URL for User Media Files
Admin > Stores > Configuration > Base URLs (Secure) > Base URL for User Media Files

And make sure you clear the cache

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment.
I have checked & confirmed that the url used in above fields is not found on product images in order confirmation email i get.

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: are you using any third party module or custom email template? product image on order confirmation email isn't native.